# Split into multiple columns based on a delimiter

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a column TASKID "3.001.2.2.1.3"

I have split them based on `.` (dot) in 4 columns with each column value:

```
TaskLevel1=3                   
TaskLevel2=3.001         
TaskLevel3=3.001.2      
TaskLevel4=3.001.2.2
```

The sample code for creating table and insert scripts are below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Task]
(
    [TaskID] [varchar](35) NULL,
    [TaskLevel1] [varchar](35) NULL,
    [TaskLevel2] [varchar](35) NULL,
    [TaskLevel3] [varchar](35) NULL,
    [TaskLevel4] [varchar](35) NULL
)


INSERT [dbo].[Task] ([TaskID], [TaskLevel1], [TaskLevel2], [TaskLevel3], [TaskLevel4]) 
VALUES (N'3.001.2.2.1', N'3', N'3.001', N'3.001.2', N'3.001.2.2')

INSERT [dbo].[Task] ([TaskID], [TaskLevel1], [TaskLevel2], [TaskLevel3], [TaskLevel4]) 
VALUES (N'3.001.2.2.1.3', N'3', N'3.001', N'3.001.2', N'3.001.2.2')
```

Comment: and what's your desired result?

Comment: i have to split the first column TASKID into four columns with values as             **TaskLevel1=3                   
TaskLevel2=3.001         
TaskLevel3=3.001.2      
TaskLevel4=3.001.2.2**

Comment: does this format always stay the same? `#.###.#.#.#....`

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (
     [TaskID] [varchar](35) NULL
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('3'),
('3.001'),
('3.001.2.2.1'),
('3.001.2.2.1.3')

;with cte([TaskID], [start], [level]) as
(
    SELECT [TaskID], 1, 1
    FROM @t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [TaskID], CHARINDEX('.', [TaskID], [start]) + 1, [level] + 1
    FROM cte
    WHERE CHARINDEX('.', [TaskID], [start]) > 0
),
cte2 as 
(
    SELECT [TaskID], LEFT([TaskID], CHARINDEX('.', [TaskID] + '.', [start]) - 1) AS [val], [level] 
    FROM cte
)
SELECT [TaskID]
    , [1] AS [TaskLevel1] 
    , [2] AS [TaskLevel2]
    , [3] AS [TaskLevel3]
    , [4] AS [TaskLevel4]
FROM cte2
PIVOT (MAX([val])
        FOR [level] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])) p
ORDER BY [TaskID]
```